# Removing 'new lines' from MySQL text field

Tags: php, mysql, csv, newline

I am trying to run a csv export on a MySQL Database via PHP. Everything is working fine until I get to the description field. Where each line is terminated by new lines in the text field. So for every line in the text field, I get a new line in the CSV. When all I want is a new line for the end of the row.

I've tried a few solutions so far, including:

`REPLACE(description, '\r\n', '\n')`

`str_replace( array( "\r" , "\n" ) ,'\n' , $data);`

```
description = REPLACE(description, description, TRIM(BOTH '\r\n' FROM description))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how important are the new lines to the content -- if you strip them out, will if affect the meaning of the text? Will you need to put them back in again?

Comment: In this instance the new lines aren't strictly needed. But for future ref, if you can advise in any ways that it can be done (i.e. the export) without losing any of the new lines, that would be awesome.

Comment: A proper CSV library should handle escaping the data for you.  After googling a bit, I'm not very confident in php in this matter, as I can't find any options that don't require file IO in the process.  I think one option might be to place a backslash in front or the newline characters.

Comment: @Paul - You'd need to embed *something* into the final output that was used instead of new lines. See my answer for some suggestions.

Comment: Cheers guys. Yeah, the descriptions already have html embedded, hence no need for the line breaks, but I never thought of escaping the new lines with a backslashes. That's the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you replacing it with `\n`?

Try to replace it with an **empty string** instead, like  `''`. Try to replace `\r\n` with `""` and `\n` with `""`

Comment: You're absolutely right. Having one of my blone moments today, copying and pasting code. It still doesn't work, but I have just realised that if I do a replace on '\n' only, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Newlines are not always `\n` ... they can be `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` and `\r` depending on the character encoding.

If you have the ability to make a new csv data file and want to change the newlines to html br tags, check out the `nl2br()` function, its really easy to use. If string replace does not work on the above newline characters, write the data to a temp file on the hard drive, then parse line by line to concatenate all newlines into a space. There are easy examples to follow in the PHP manual.

I actually had the opposite issue, where I had to go through a csv file that was already created and find the newlines. The answer in that case was using a regular expression, but I was fortunate in that the first and last columns of data were unique enough to parse and capture all the data in between. Another option would have been to remove all newlines and collect the data based on the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [**preg_replace()**](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data);
```

But you can always use [**str_replace()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (it's faster)

```
str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing with `\\n` or even HTML `<br>` tags. This will enable to you re-instate the line-breaks later on.